# Why is my data coming back as a null from firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve some data from Firebase to populate into my RecycleView but every time I attempt this my RecycleView appears empty.

I have already created my adapter and set up my Recycleview and attempted to load the data from Firebase but nothing shows up. When I try to log the information it comes back as null. Some help would be appreciated.

This is how my database is set up

```
 Post
 -Ljl__LUiOJ2YMAK5NHI
 desc: "Product info"
 id:   "sH8LzoaH9UaXahlmssixTpvQy8q2"
 image: "content://media/external/images/media/323211"




 //Retrieves information stored inside Post node...
public void fetchUserInfo() {
    postRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Post");
    postRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
               value = ds.getValue(Post.class);
               postList.add(value);
            }
            adapter = new Adapter(Shop_Activity.this, postList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.i("Error", databaseError.toString());

        }
    });


}
```

**Adapter :**

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Post> userPost;

    public Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Post> userPost){
        this.context = context;
        this.userPost = userPost;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.shop_layout_design,viewGroup, false));

    }

    //this is where you set the value for the ui elements
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        viewHolder.title.setText(userPost.get(i).getDescription());
        viewHolder.description.setText(userPost.get(i).getUserID());
        Picasso.get().load(userPost.get(i).getPostImage()).into(viewHolder.postImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userPost.size();
    }


    //links up ui elements
    class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView title;
        TextView description;
        ImageView postImage;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
        }
    }
}
```

**Post class**

```
public class Post {

    private String desc;
    private String id;
    private String image;



    public Post(){
    }

    public void setdesc(String desc){
        this.desc = desc;

    }
    public void setimage(String image){
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void setid(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getdesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public String getimage(){
        return image;
    }
    public String getid(){
        return  id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you log data in `postlist` ?

Comment: Yeah when I try to log my postList I get this message [com.example.selfcare.Post@c24e8cd]

Comment: The things you have done is little bit wrong because you put everything in for loop which will repeat the process again and again

Comment: Instead of describing how you database looks like, please add a screenshot of it. Beside that, show us in which place of your code are you trying to log the content of your array. Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I copied and paste my database that's exactly how it looks, and I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

add this after setting the adapter